# Configuration problem with one to many relationship using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a parent `user` table, and a child `userStatus`, so many users have one status.
The user table have a child `personal` and this table have a lot of other entry and more child tables.
When I try to add a user I get the following error message:

> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a
> child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mediadb`.`user`,
> CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_UserStatusId`) REFERENCES
> `userstatus` (`PK_StatusId`))

User table:

```
    {
        public user()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(TypeName = "int(11)")]
        public int userID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(70)]
        public string? email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(40)]
        public string? password { get; set; }
        public DateTime? registrationDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "int(11)")]
        public int FK_UserStatusId { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("User")]
        public virtual UserStatus? UserStatus { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("users")]
        public virtual ICollection<Personal>? personal { get; set; } = new HashSet<Personal>();
    }
```

UserStatus Table:

```
public partial class UserStatus
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(TypeName = "int(11)")]
        public int PK_StatusId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string statusName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string? description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<user>? User { get; set; } = new HashSet<user>();
    }
```

FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<user>(entity =>
{
      entity.HasOne(s => s.UserStatus)
      .WithMany(g => g.User)
      .HasForeignKey(s => s.FK_UserStatusId);
});
```

The database is Mysql, and when I insert data the reference is works perfectly and the user table references to the userStatus (As expected)

On request, here is the mysql log:

```
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 58212177; transaction id 72906
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.20-MariaDB-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2024-01-26 16:49:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240126 16:49:45
```

General log:

```
F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 10.4.20-MariaDB-log (mariadb.org binary distribution). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: F:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock
Time            Id Command  Argument
240126 16:48:08      8 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on mediadb
             8 Query    SET NAMES utf8mb4
             8 Query    SELECT `u`.`userID`, `u`.`FK_UserStatusId`, `u`.`email`, `u`.`password`, `u`.`registrationDate`
FROM `user` AS `u`
WHERE `u`.`email` = 'teszt@teszt.com'
LIMIT 2
             8 Query    SET NAMES utf8mb4
             8 Query    set session transaction isolation level repeatable read
             8 Query    start transaction
             8 Query    INSERT INTO `user` (`FK_UserStatusId`, `email`, `password`, `registrationDate`)
VALUES (0, 'teszt@teszt.hu', 'wwwww4444wwww', timestamp('2024-01-26 15:48:08.798646'));
SELECT `userID`
FROM `user`
WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `userID` = LAST_INSERT_ID()
             8 Query    rollback
```

Endpoit when it fails:

```
[HttpPost("Signup")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult<user>> SignUp(RegisterForm user)
        {
            user.UserStatus = null;
            if (user != null)
            {
                user userExistsByEmail = await _context.user.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.email == user.email);
                if (userExistsByEmail != null)
                {
                    return Ok("used email");
                }

                user newUser = new()
                {
                    email = user.email,
                    password = user.Password,
                    registrationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    personal = user.personal,
                };

                
                _context.user.Add(newUser);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Ok("success");
            }
            return BadRequest("error");
        }
```

Comment: Where's the code that fails? If you try to insert a `User` with a non-existent status you'll get an error in all databases

Comment: What does the `UserStatus` *table* contain? ORMs like EF deal with entities, not tables. The inappropriately named `user` class is an application entity, not table. That entity's badly named `FK_UserStatusId` property is a non-nullable int which means its value is always `0` unless set to something else. If the `UserStatus` table has no row with `PK_StatusId` 0 (another bad name), you'll get an FK violation.

Comment: The log shows exactly this `INSERT INTO \`user\` (\`FK_UserStatusId\`, \`email\`, \`password\`, \`registrationDate\`)
VALUES (0,...`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL and other RDBMSs as well, if you have t1 and t2 and t1.fk is a foreign key referencing t2.pk, then whenever you are to insert/update a record in t1 (which is the user in this case), then you will need to make sure that the fk (which is FK_UserStatusId in this case) has a value that already exists in the referenced table as primary key.

The error message tells you that you did not proceed in this manner.

Comment: Not just MySQL. This would fail in all databases. If the OP's code called `Add` on a new user with a *new* status with a db-generated key, the new status would be inserted automatically.

Comment: It has, this is the table: CREATE TABLE `userstatus` (
  `PK_StatusId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `statusName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_StatusId`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Select * from userStatus:
PK_StatusId statusName description 
1 activated 

Szia amúgy, köszi a segítséget :)

Comment: @qkory can you look into your MySQL logs and tell us what the exact failed query was?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the comment, edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: log files added to the original answer

Comment: You are passing 0 as FK_UserStatusId. Do you have a record inside your UserStatus table? I think you do not have such a status. What statuses do you have in that table?

Comment: Thank you, you were right! Because I've used Dtos, the FK_UserStatusId were not passed into the user model, and thus not sent to database. It's a stupid mistake. Szuperül megy, ezer köszi!

Comment: I am glad it ended up working. if the answer helped you solve the problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer. Örülök, hogy segíthettem!